# Extract pattern and subsequent n elements from array and count number of occurences

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have an array of doubles like this:

```
C = [1 2 3 4 0 3 2 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 150 30]
```

i want to find the pattern [1 2 3 4] within the array and then store the 2 values after that pattern with it like:

```
A = [1 2 3 4 0 3]
B = [1 2 3 4 150 30]
```

i can find the pattern like this but i don't know how to get and store 2 values after that with the previous one.

And after finding A, B if i want to find the number of occurrences of each arrays within array C how can i do that?

```
indices = cellfun(@(c) strfind(c,pattern), C, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're fine with a cell array output, this works fine:

```
C = [1 2 3 4 0 3 2 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 150 30 42 1 2 3 4 0 3]
p = [1 2 3 4]
n = 2

% full patttern length - 1
dn = numel(p) + n - 1

%// find indices
ind = strfind(C,p)

%// pre check if pattern at end of array
if ind(end)+ dn  > numel(C), k = -1; else k = 0; end

%// extracting
temp = arrayfun(@(x) C(x:x+dn), ind(1:end+k) , 'uni', 0)

%// post processing
[out, ~, idx] = unique(vertcat(temp{:}),'rows','stable')
occ = histcounts(idx).'
```

If the array `C` ends with at least `n` elements after the last occurrence of the pattern `p`, you can use the short form:

```
out = arrayfun(@(x) C(x:x+n+numel(p)-1), strfind(C,p) , 'uni', 0)
```

---

```
out =

     1     2     3     4     0     3
     1     2     3     4   150    30

occ =

     2
     1
```

Comment: For the problem mentioned above it works (+1). However, can you make more general so that it works also when the vector ends with `p`:  `C = [1 2 3 4 0 3 2 5 6 7 1 2 3 4]`

Comment: @John In that case the last pattern should be ignored?

Comment: But it returned an error for me: Error in @(x)C(x:x+n+numel(p)-1)

Comment: @John have a look at my array

Comment: thank you for the modification, the new solution is optimal in my opinion.

Comment: @John I corrected another time for the case `C = [1 2 3 4 0 3 2 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 5]` - this should the most general way now

Comment: @thewaywewalk to find the occurrence of each cell array of output `out = arrayfun(@(x) C(x:x+n+numel(p)-1), length(strfind(C,p)) , 'uni', 0)`  i should try something like that but in your first code `out = arrayfun(@(x) C(x:x+n+numel(p)-1), ind(1:end+k) , 'uni', 0)`  how does it look like?

Comment: @lighting what to you want to say me with that comment?

Comment: Well, i mean how can i calculate the number of occurrence of each cell array of output within array C?

Comment: @lighting `numberOfOccurrences = numel(out)` ?

Comment: @thewaywewalk No, the number of occurrences of out{1}, out{2} within `C = [1 2 3 4 0 3 2 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 150 30]`

Comment: @lighting I don't get that additional question, maybe ask a new one with a clear example or edit your question?

Comment: @lighting so basically for `[1 2 3 4 0 3 2 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 150 30 1 2 3 4 0 3]` you want `out = {[1 2 3 4 0 3], [1 2 3 4 150 30]}` and `nout = [2 1]`?

Comment: @thewaywewalk Exactly.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Thanks bro! and i really owe you one.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution can be:

```
C = [1 2 3 4 0 3 2 5 6 7 1 2 3 4 150 30];
pattern = [1 2 3 4];
numberOfAddition = 2;
outputs = zeros(length(A),length(pattern)+ numberOfAddition); % preallocation
numberOfFoundPattern =  1;
lengthOfConsider = length(C) - length(pattern) - numberOfAddition;
for i = 1:lengthOfConsider 
     if(sum(C(i:i+length(pattern)) - pattern) == 0) % find pattern
         outputs(numberOfFoundPattern,:) = C(i:i+length(pattern)+numberOfAddition);
         numberOfFoundPattern = numberOfFoundPattern + 1;
     end
end
outputs = outputs(1:numberOfFoundPattern - 1,:);
```